# SQL Web Replication, Create New Subscription Programmatically

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, database-replication

Anyone know if it is possible to programmatically create new SQL WEB replication subscriptions on the fly?

I can do it programmatically across a VPN, using standard database to database synchronization, but can't seem to find any way to create a subscription on the fly when using web replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a subscription and configure it to use Web Synchronization programmatically using T-SQL (and/or RMO if this is SQL Server 2012 or earlier).

Using T-SQL:

- At the Publisher execute [sp_addmergesubscription](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187717.aspx) and specify
  values for **@publication**, **@subscriber**, **@subscriber_db**, and
  a value of **pull** for **@subscription_type**.
- Then at the Subscriber, execute [sp_addmergepullsubscription](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189456.aspx)
  specifying values for **@publication**, **@publisher**, and
  **@publisher_db**.
- Then at the Subscriber, if this is Standard Edition or higher,
  execute [sp_addmergepullsubscription_agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187722.aspx) specifying values for
  **@publisher**, **@publisher_db**, **@publication**, a value of **1** for **@use_web_sync**, **@internet_url**,
  **@internet_security_mode**, **@internet_login**, and **@internet_password**.

If the subscription creation process does not have access to both publisher and subscriber, then you will need to create **anonymous** subscriptions.

Using T-SQL:

- At the Subscriber execute [sp_addmergepullsubscription](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189456.aspx) and
  specify a value of **anonymous** for **@subscriber_type** and values
  for **@publication**, **@publisher**, and **@publisher_db**.
- Then at the Subscriber, if this is Standard Edition or higher,
  execute [sp_addmergepullsubscription_agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187722.aspx) specifying values for
  **@publisher**, **@publisher_db**, **@publication**, a value of **1** for **@use_web_sync**, **@internet_url**,
  **@internet_security_mode**, **@internet_login**, and **@internet_password**.

This is covered in [How to: Configure a Subscription to Use Web Synchronization (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345206.aspx)

Comment: The issue we are seeing is at step 2, creating the pull subscription.  For that step, don't the two SQL Servers have to be able to see one another?  We need users outside the firewall to be able to create a subscription dynamically.  We have a service than can run a stored procedure on the publisher to create the merge subscription, but the subscriber will have no path to the publisher, except through the web replication subscription.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  If there is no possible way for subscription creation process to have access to both publisher and subscriber, then you will need to create anonymous subscriptions.  That is covered in the section To configure a subscription to use Web synchronization for Subscribers that can only connect to the Publisher through a Web server using HTTP.

Comment: Thanks.  We'll give that a shot.